# ap-hotspot not working

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ap-hotspot

A day earlier I messed up with some network-manager configuration files in order to increase wifi range of my ap-hotspot hotspot on Ubuntu 14.04

Earlier it was working fine, but now I have got some error in it.
on running `sudo ap-hotspot start` I get Another process running error. Sometimes it stuck at "Starting Hotspot".

I have tried all ways like reinstalling ap-hotspot , deleting tmp/hotspot.pid, etc.

Please help as I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu again from scratch because it took around a week for me to setup my Ubuntu for my use.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work any more. Just simply add a new shared wireless Network and change it;s mode in the configuration file (/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections) from `infrastructure` to `ap`

Comment: actualy using this method, wifi is not connected to windows 10 operating systems, but using ap-hotspot is supporting on all android and windows OS. I just want that back working again.

Comment: could you tell me how to edit range of wifi hotspot created using your method.